# Find duplicate values in comma separated rows with random data

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling with this for a while and couldn't find a solution.

I have a Google Sheets file with comma-separated data in two columns as per the screenshot attached.

Screenshot of the two columns[image]

text from the screenshot:

```
soon,son,so,on,no                               N/A
kind,kid,din,ink,kin,in                         dink
sing,sign,sin,gin,in,is                         gis,ins,sig,gins
farm,arm,ram,far,mar,am                         arf
may,yam,am,my                                   N/A
tulip,lip,lit,pit,put,tip                       piu,pul,til,tui,tup,litu,ptui,puli,uplit
gift,it,if,fit,fig                              gif,git
hear,are,ear,hare,era,her                       hae,rah,rhea
dish,his,is,hi,hid                              dis,ids,sidh
trip,pit,rip,tip,it                             N/A
wife,few,if,we                                  fie
thaw,what,hat,at                                haw,taw,twa,wat,wha
red,deer,reed                                   ere,dee,ree,dere,dree,rede
as,save,vase,sea                                ave,sae,sev,vas,aves
from,for,form,of,or                             fro,mor,rom
won,now,on,own,no                               N/A
sport,port,spot,post,stop,sort,top,opt,pot,pro  tor,sotrot,ops,tors,tops,trop,pots,opts,rots,pros,prost,strop,ports
```

I would love to have in another column a formula to show if in these two columns there are any duplicate values.

Thank you in advance for your help... it's been weeks without success haha

Comment: What did you already try? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well, I've tried COUNTIF, COUNTIFS, and AND formulas in different variations from different blogs, etc. But so far it seems the only thing I can achieve is to return TRUE or FALSE value if the rows are precisely identical.

In my case, the rows are never identical...

Comment: I added the text from the screenshot. Because the probem has nothing (much) to do with 'Google Sheets'

Comment: Thank you Luuk. Much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *in these two columns there are any duplicate values.*  Are you looking at each substring in each cell in both columns to find duplicates?  Just one cell? Cells in the same row?  And what version of Excel?  What would be your output given the data you present.  Why do you have Google Sheets in the title but not in the Tags?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I did write in the question initially that this file is on Google Sheets. Unfortunately, Luuk decided to remove that from the question title... anyway, it's on Google Sheets.

Comment: And my other questions?

Comment: For your other questions, I'm going to try to explain again. I would like the formula to check for duplicates in the rows of column A and column B and then tell me in column C if there are any duplicates. The way it can tell me could be the exact duplicate value or just a TRUE or FALSE value, anything to signal that there's a duplicate on that specific row. I hope this explains the concept ... it's as simple as that.

Comment: So, to clarify, do you want to compare **all** the words (separated by comma) in the cells of column A against those in the column B and return true if there are duplicates right? Are you ok with using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) for this or do you just want plain Google Sheet formulas ?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf thank you for jumping in on this. To confirm the scenario, yes, we should compare the words separated by commas in the cells of column A against the ones in column B. Using Apps Scripts or a Google Sheet formula, both solutions would work ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel for Windows O365 with the `UNIQUE` and `FILTERXML` functions,

and if you mean to consider both columns together as if they were a single piece of data,

then try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,$A$1:$A$17,$B$1:$B$17),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[.=following-sibling::*]"))
```

[image]

If that is not what you want, please clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you Ron for your help! I mentioned in an earlier comment, I am building this on Google Sheets... the formula unfortunately doesn't work but it does seem to be exactly what I would love to achieve !

Comment: @IulianOlaru I provided this since you did not originally include `google sheets` as a tag in your question.  AFAIK, `Sheets` does not have the equivalent of `FILTERXML`, so this solution will not work for you.

Comment: Yeah, sorry Ron, first question on Stack... I wrote Google Sheets in the title and the question... I did not think that I have to write it as a tag too. Sincere apologies.

Answer (score 0):

First place your data in columns **A** and **B** of an Excel worksheet.  Then run this short VBA macro:

```
Sub report()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, c As Collection, K As Long
    Set rng = Range("A1:B17")
    Set c = New Collection
    K = 1
    
    For Each r In rng
        arr = Split(r.Value, ",")
        For Each a In arr
            On Error Resume Next
                c.Add a, CStr(a)
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    Err.Number = 0
                    Cells(K, "C").Value = a
                    K = K + 1
                End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next a
    Next r
    Range("C:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Set c = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

The duplicates appear in column **C**

Comment: Hey Gary, this could definitely work but I am trying to achieve this on Google Sheets actually ...

Comment: By the way, I'm on macOS with Apple Numbers... I understand Numbers doesn't read VBA... sorry if this is complicated :-)

Comment: There is a similar scripting language for Google Sheets, I will take a look later.

Comment: Thank you very much Gary... this could be a lifesaver!

Comment: Hey Gary, any chance you would have a solution for this ? It would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your question: you want to find out if there are any words delimited by commas matching between the cells of two different columns.

For this solution I have used [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). The following commented piece of code will find matching words between the two columns. Moreover, as the function used is an `onEdit()` trigger, it will automatically detect any changes done in either of these columns and automatically find out new matches or matches that are no longer there and update the value of cell `C1`:

```js
function onEdit() {
  // get current sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  
  // get values from our columns. This returns a 2D array that is flatten into a
  // 1 D array to then convert it into a string where its elements are separated
  // by a comma and white spaces are removed (so that a matches space + a for example)
  var colA = sheet.getRange('A1:A2').getValues().flat().join().replace(/\s/g, '');
  var colB = sheet.getRange('B1:B2').getValues().flat().join().replace(/\s/g, '');
  
  // Create two arrays where each element is a word delimited by a comma in their original
  // string
  var ArrayA = colA.split(',');
  var ArrayB = colB.split(',');
  
  // find matches in these two arrays and return these matches
  var matchingValues = ArrayA.filter(value => ArrayB.includes(value));
  
  // set the value of C1 to the words that the filter has matched between our two columns
  // join is used to display all the matching elements of the match array
  sheet.getRange('C1').setValue(matchingValues.join());
  
}
```

Demo:

[image]

If you do not know how to open the script editor, you can access it on your Google Sheets menu bar under **Tools-> Script editor**.